# concatenate FirstName and LastName in a DropDownListFor()

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How to concatenate FirstName and LastName for a DropDownListFor(), what i am trying is not working here is my code.

View Model

```
public class ViewModelUser
    {
     public SelectList User { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string SelectedUID { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller

```
 public ActionResult GiveReview()
        {
            ViewModelUser viewModelUser = new ViewModelUser();
            viewModelUser.User = new SelectList(dbContext.Users.Where(u => u.Deleted != true).Select(us => new { us.FirstName, us.LastName, us.UID }), "UID", "FirstName" + "LastName");
            return View(viewModelUser );
        }
```

View

```
@model WebApplication22.ViewModels.ViewModelUser
@using (Html.BeginForm("GiveReview", "ProvideReview", FormMethod.Post, new { Id = "ratingsForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="profile-name">Select User</label>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedUID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.User, "-Select User-", new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>        
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn btn-primary">
                    Submit
                </button>           
}
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide what you get in use class after the Db call. Then only I can able to provide answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to concatenate the values in the `Select` clause

```
viewModelUser.User = new SelectList(dbContext.Users
    .Where(u => u.Deleted != true).ToList()
    .Select(u => new { FullName = String.Format("{0} {1}", u.FirstName, u.LastName), UID = u.UID }),
    "UID", "FullName");
```

Comment: i am getting this error " LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."